# JSON.loads выдает ошибку

Tags: python, синтаксис

В переменной есть и HTML теги и JavaScript данные.
Нужно  в словарь Python поместить  часть спарсенной страницы ,которая выглядит : "ключ" : "значение".

Этот скрипт почему-то выдает ошибку

> TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not BeautifulSoup

```
import requests # модуль для парсинга
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup #модуль для парсинга
import json 

s = requests.Session()
loging = s.get(URL, headers=HEADERS, params=None)
soup = BeautifulSoup(loging.content, 'html.parser')
json_dat = json.loads(soup)
```

Comment: Могу вам посоветовать? Не задавайте дальнейшие вопросы, пока вы не прочитаете по крайней мере [Beautiful Soup на русском языке](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc.ru/), потому что таким образом вы ничего не научитесь.

Comment: Вы бы написали как надо,я бы научился. Для этого учителя и нужны,что бы время экономить.

Comment: @Webos зачем кому-то экономить Ваше время, если Вы не собираетесь економить чужое?

Comment: я хорошо изучил Beautiful Soup, но этот модуль -работа с тегами. А у меня в средине страницы json данные. они из себя представляют словарь - "ключ" : "данные". С этой частью страницы Beautiful Soup не умеет работать. Этот модуль работает с простыми HTML тегами или с селекторами, которые вытаскивают все содержимое тега,если селектор в нем найден. –